# Multi-tab in message extension like shown in the microsoft documentation

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

How can I add multiple tab in message extension in Bot Framework using C# like as shown in this image here ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMImK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it by adding multiple search commands in the manifest file. Sharing part of JSON below.

```
    "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "448ec85c-4395-4f80-b5a1-cd3bdefd1f5b",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "searchQuery",
          "context": [
            "compose",
            "commandBox"
          ],
          "description": "Test command to run query",
          "title": "Search",
          "type": "query",
          "initialRun": true,
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "searchQuery",
              "title": "Search Query",
              "description": "Your search query",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        },
{
          "id": "searchQuery2",
          "context": [
            "compose",
            "commandBox"
          ],
          "description": "Test command to run query2",
          "title": "Search2",
          "type": "query",
          "initialRun": true,
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "searchQuery2",
              "title": "Search Query2",
              "description": "Your search query2",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        },
{
          "id": "searchQuery3",
          "context": [
            "compose",
            "commandBox"
          ],
          "description": "Test command to run query",
          "title": "Search3",
          "type": "query",
          "initialRun": true,
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "searchQuery3",
              "title": "Search Query3",
              "description": "Your search query3",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
  ]
```

[image]

Here is the sample - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search